collectionView "scrollToItem" after check for "dataSource?.collectionView(self, cellForItemAt:" functions on iOS 18 leads to a crash
I have this extension to scroll to the first collectionView cell:
extension UICollectionView {

func scrollToFirst(inSection: Int = 0, animated: Bool = false) {
     if let _ = dataSource?.collectionView(self, cellForItemAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: inSection)) { // MARK: Checks if collectionView is filled
            scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: inSection), at: .right, animated: animated)
        }
     }
}

It works on iOS -18 but on iOS 18.0 it crashes.

func scrollToFirst(inSection: Int = 0, animated: Bool = false) {
    if visibleCells.count > 0 { // MARK: Checks if collectionView is filled
        scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: inSection), at: .right, animated: animated)
    }
 }

}

Your dataSource somehow has not loaded yet. Although the cell's instance is available, I believe the section isn't ready to use, you may want to print out the section by numberOfSections. It can lead to the exception below:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to scroll the collection view to an out-of-bounds item

So, it's better to check if the index is valid before scrolling:
if self.numberOfSections > inSection {
    //TODO: - other stuff
}

